# LockTwo from "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming"

Tags: locking, mutex

Here is mutext implementation for two threads from "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming"

```
private int victim;
// thread-local index, 0 or 1

public void lock() {
  int i = ThreadID.get();
  victim = i;                 // let the other go first
  while (victim == i) {}      // spin
}
public void unlock() {}
```

They state that this code deadlocks if "one thread runs ahead of the other". Can anyone describe an example of interleaved execution when no deadlock occurs.

Comment: The question (imoh) to answer is what the state looks like that *causes* deadlock; since the two threads write to a shared variable (victim) and since the threads unlock each other's execution by locking (in contrast to the "LockOne" algorithm) it's not obvious how you would be able to get this to deadlock in the first place..everywhere I've looked people seem to have skipped that bit and just taken the answer verbatum from the book. Or I'm staring right at it and failing to see it.

Comment: @SonarJetLens take a look at my answer and let me know if it makes sense. I kind of hope a concurrency expert can help us out here :)

Answer (score 2):

I may be flawed in my understanding, in which case somebody can hopefully clarify (cc @SonarJetLens).

In the case where one thread runs completely ahead of the other, we have that, for example, Thread A acquires the lock and waits, because it's the victim. It waits indefinitely until Thread B comes along and sets itself to be the victim, thereby letting A go through to its critical section. In this case I don't see any deadlock occurring: by definition, a deadlock is when no progress is made by *any* thread.

However, consider the case where Thread A never tries to reacquire the lock. In this case, Thread B will wait indefinitely, never able to reach it's critical section. For me, this looks more like *starvation*, meaning that Thread B was starved and never able to acquire the thread.

If the program ends there, then Thread A has made some "progress" by executing it's critical section, and Thread B has not, therefore there is no deadlock. However, there is starvation, since Thread B was trying to acquire the lock and never succeeded, thereby contradicting the definition of starvation freedom.

I hope this makes sense and I'm not making any terminology or definition mistakes here, and I really hope someone clarifies :).

Comment: Good sense! The book could do well to elaborate on this point, in particular as "starvation" and "deadlock" are such fundamentally different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

After reading it again today, i think i got the idea behind "The LockTwo class is inadequate because it deadlocks if one thread runs `completely` before the other."

if thread A and B are serialized, which means thread B waits thread A to finish, then thread A will never get the lock by "LockTwo", that's a deadlock by definition: `Freedom from Deadlock: If some thread attempts to acquire the lock, then some thread will succeed in acquiring the lock.`.

More apparent if the author writes "The LockTwo class is inadequate because it deadlocks if there is only one thread. (Although there is no need of the lock)

Answer (score -1):

Basically a thread will be stuck waiting in the while loop until another thread enters lock() and changes the value of the victim field.

If one thread runs completely ahead of another, i.e.

```
thread A writes victim = A -> 
thread A reads Victim != A -> 
thread A do Critical Section -> 
thread B writes victim = B -> 
thread B reads Victim != B -> 
thread B do Critical Section
```

This will cause deadlock because the event `thread B writes victim = B` must come before `thread A reads Victim != A`, otherwise the event thread A reads `Victim != A` will block indefinitely.

Interleaved operations prevent deadlock, because, for example, when thread B writes `victim = B`, allowing A to complete and return its critical section, thread B is now waiting in the while loop until `victim != B`. Thread B will return from the while loop when either Thread A  re-enters lock and changes the victim or another Thread C enters lock and changes the victim, allowing B to proceed to its critical section. etc

Comment: Can you clarify? Thread A reads Victim !=A is only possible if B has written Victim=B between A writing Victim=A and then reading it, but then all that happens is that A enters the CS and B sits waiting forever...or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I will too attempt to answer this, though I am a novice in this department.

Consider the following situation (A & B are threads):

`writeA(victim=A) -> readA(victim != A) -> CSA`

Similarly

`writeB(victim=B) -> readB(victim != B) -> CSB`

Now consider the following case:

`Case 1:` When one thread runs completely ahead of another, i.e. `A -> B`

As `thread A` starts first, it sets the `victim=A` and waits, in the meanwhile `thread B` cannot start as it is waiting for the thread A to complete its execution of the critical section. Thus `thread A` is waiting for `thread B` to change the `victim` but `B` is waiting for the `thread A` to complete its `CSA`. Hence a deadlock will take place as the two threads are waiting on two different conditions:

`Thread A is waiting so that thread B sets victim=B whereas thread B is waiting so that thread A completes its critical section (CSA).`

`Case 2:` When threads have interleaved execution.

In this situation since both threads start at almost the same time (and assuming they run again and again, probably in a loop), they will alternately set the victim thus allowing each other to run of course alternately.